# How to write EPC into QR with ZPL

Tags: rfid, zpl, epc

How can I write an EPC into a QR with ZPL. The following is not working

```
^BQ,2,3^FDHA," + "^FN0" + "^FS
^FN0^RFR,H^FS
```

I am able to write the EPC on a label with a placeholder like:

```
^FO230,110^A0N,18,10^FN1^FS
^FN1^RFR,H^FS
```